# data.table (R) paste value from a specific row while aggregating by group

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I'm dealing with a quirky one.
I have some data like so:

```
dt<-data.table(time = c('13:00','13:00','13:00','13:15','13:15'),group=c('A','A','B','A','B'),code=c('11b','16b','22c','9c','7y'))

        time group code
    1: 13:00     A  11b
    2: 13:00     A  16b
    3: 13:00     B  22c
    4: 13:15     A   9c
    5: 13:15     B   7y
```

I'm trying to do the following. Create a new column (`:= Fgroup`) that takes on a value conditioning on `group`, and aggregating by `time`. 
So, if `group == A`, it will be enough to paste the value in `code`. If `group == B`, I need to paste the code (or codes if there are many), which are present for group A, by `time`.

In other words:

```
        time group code Fcode
    1: 13:00     A  11b  11b
    2: 13:00     A  16b  16b
    3: 13:00     B  22c  11b,16b
    4: 13:15     A   9c  9c
    5: 13:15     B   7y  9c
```

Any easy way out?
Thank you

Comment: there is only ever group A or group B?

Comment: and only ever one row per time for group B?

Comment: There's also a group C, but the same rule applies as for group A (just paste the same value). There can be more rows for group B by time.

Comment: Grouping on time alone, add a new column with all the pasted values of code. Then join this to your original table. Group on time and group and create a new column useing an ifelse to use either code or your previously created column

Comment: How do you decide on the hierarchy of the groups? Why aren't you checking if there was overlapping time from group B to group A? Is group C should be compared with both of group A and B? Your questions isn't very clear.

Comment: In your desired output should the column be called `Fgroup` instead of `Fcode`? For what you want to do, you can write a function `f` that returns the `Fcode` value and assign it to the column using `:=`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm dealing with a flawed dataset that contains error, and I'm trying to fix this, this might be the reason why the logic seems weird. The thing is that the code for group B should be the same as the one assigned to group A by time, but it's been coded incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't say that the logic seems weird. I've asked a specific question: How do you decide what's the hierarchy of the groups? And what to do with the groups after B. In other words A < B < C < etc.? What happens when there are more groups than letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean to have something like this?

```r
library(data.table)

dt[, Fcode := paste(code[group == 'A'], collapse = ","), by = time][group == 'A', Fcode := code]
```

which gives

```
> dt
    time group code   Fcode
1: 13:00     A  11b     11b
2: 13:00     A  16b     16b
3: 13:00     B  22c 11b,16b
4: 13:15     A   9c      9c
5: 13:15     B   7y      9c
```

**Sample data:**

```
dt <- data.table(time = c('13:00','13:00','13:00','13:15','13:15'),
                 group= c('A','A','B','A','B'),
                 code = c('11b','16b','22c','9c','7y'))
```

Comment: This is also very manual and won't scale to anything more than two groups. Or groups with other names.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping on time alone, add a new column with all the pasted values of code. Then join this to your original table. Group on time and group and create a new column using an ifelse to use either code or your previously created column

```
dt <- dt[,.(code_temp=paste(ifelse(group!="B",code,""),collapse=", ")), by="time"][
dt, on="time"][
, Fcode := ifelse(group!="B",code,code_temp)][
group=="B",Fcode := substr(Fcode,1,nchar(Fcode)-2)]
```

The last bit of code removes the trailing comma.

This matches your description of the problem and the output in your question but I am unsure about your reference to group C etc.

Comment: This is very manual. How OP is suppose to use this? Write each group manually?

Comment: OP has not shared enough information to say, but presumably something like `%in%` at worst. It's how I understood their question.

Comment: If the question is not clear, there is no reason to answer it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg The hierarchy of the groups is as follows: the code for A and C remains unchanged. the code for B takes on the value(s) on A. The timestamp gives us information on which A code should replace the B code. We only have 3 groups.

Comment: @DavidArenburg OP specified that group C should be treated like group A, and has not implied the existence of further groups. Using `!="B"` should be sufficient. But I appreciate your advice.

Comment: Well, OP accepted a solution where `B` is treated the same as `C` rather like `A`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I noticed. They did say the opposite though, in a comment to their question.